# Why Backpropagation is in negative

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

New to Backpropagation.

In this example here and in all other example we calculate new weights by finding the derivative of the sigmoid

https://repl.it/@vzhou842/An-Introduction-to-Neural-Networks

I know that derivatives can show the changing rate. like if we change the value of the variable the amount will change based on the derivative rate.

Now

the new weight is

```
    # --- Update weights and biases
    # Neuron h1
    self.w1 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h1 * d_h1_d_w1
    self.w2 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h1 * d_h1_d_w2
    self.b1 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h1 * d_h1_d_b1

    # Neuron h2
    self.w3 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h2 * d_h2_d_w3
    self.w4 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h2 * d_h2_d_w4
    self.b2 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h2 * d_h2_d_b2

    # Neuron o1
    self.w5 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_w5
    self.w6 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_w6
    self.b3 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_b3
```

Why the new weight is minus the derivative?

why it is not to add

i mean to be something like this

```
    # --- Update weights and biases
    # Neuron h1
    self.w1 += learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h1 * d_h1_d_w1
    self.w2 += learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h1 * d_h1_d_w2
    self.b1 += learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h1 * d_h1_d_b1

    # Neuron h2
    self.w3 += learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h2 * d_h2_d_w3
    self.w4 += learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h2 * d_h2_d_w4
    self.b2 += learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h2 * d_h2_d_b2

    # Neuron o1
    self.w5 += learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_w5
    self.w6 += learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_w6
    self.b3 += learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_b3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it's an efficient implementation of the [gradient descent](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Gradient_descent) algorithm. Gradient of a function points towards the steepest increase direction. So, the inverse of it is the steepest decrease direction. By moving towards the negative gradient (with a suitable learning rate), your cost function will decrease. If we were maximizing maximizing, we'd go towards the positive gradient. That's why if you negate your loss function, treat it as a gain function, you can actually add the gradient instead of subtracting it. Note that, the two minus signs will cancel out each other and you'll arrive at the same solution, if the procedure is deterministic, e.g. doesn't contain random interference, shuffling etc.

Comment: Thanks, but the steep down is for the MSE function, we may reach the minimal of MSE by having a higher weight w1, w2,...  still confused

Comment: steepest down is not specific to any loss function, such as mse. If we have a differentiable $f(x)$ to be minimized, and a starting point $x_0$, the gradient descent is basically applying the following $$x_1=x_0-c\nabla f(x)|_{x=x_0}$$

Comment: Thanks again, can you point me to any materials that explains this further?

Comment: I think the wiki page description is quite useful, you can go over lots of materials (videos maybe useful) online for having the intuition (and think about 1D first, draw the derivatives yourself) and then you may want to review the gradient descent section of Stepten Boyd's Convex Opt. book. Although it focuses on convex opt. problems, I find it illuminating.